# Bootstrap modal works on it's own, but not from button click

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

Based on the [live demo](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#live-demo) in the Bootstrap examples, I've made [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/96mhm1qp/2/) to show a dialog.

Then [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/96mhm1qp/1/) should bring up the dialog on click, but is not working:

```
<button type='button' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal'>Click here</button>
```

It may be obvious, but what am I missing from the above-linked live demo?

Comment: Add jQuery to JSFiddle (must be placed before `bootstrap.min.js` file).

Comment: Actually, you are missing added `jQuery` lib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had some trouble getting this to work, I'm not entirely sure, but I think that the issue was mainly the '*External Resources*' on JSFiddle.

I have added the jQuery CDN to the fiddle, you can find it here:

https://jsfiddle.net/7ww5ra98/1/

Here is the HTML:

```
<button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Click Here</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Popup Dialog</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Wow, it works!</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Reset Password</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope you found this useful.

Comment: Yes, it seemed to need jQuery.  Thanks for removing the labels & non-essentials!